# Javascript to pull in specific stored proc fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to javascript so be gentle with me! I am trying to update code that currently pulls in all fields from a stored proc but I only want to select some of theses fields.
The data is currently displayed in JSON format. Here is the code below that pulls in all the stored proc fields:

```
return (
        <div>
            {
                isDataCallRunning &&
                <Loader />
            }
            {
                !isDataCallRunning && isError &&
                <div>display error message</div>
            }
            {
                !isDataCallRunning && !isError &&
                <div className="u-flex u-flex--column" style={{background:"white", color:"black"}}>
                    {
                        Object.entries(data).map(item => {
                            return (
                                <div className="u-flex u-flex--between u-flex--u-flex" style={{border: "1px solid gray", padding:"0.5rem"}}>
                                   {/* <div className="row"> */}
                                    <div>{item[0]+': '}</div>
                                    <div>{item[1]}</div>
                                
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            }
```

Any ideas how i should go about updating this so i can specify particular fields from the stored proc?
Thanks!
Blowers

Comment: What is a stored proc in relation to React?

Comment: The stored proc is where I am pulling the data from, React is being used to display the data in the front end

Comment: If you called it a JSON file people would understand that better. Stored procedures are generally to do with SQL databases. Or are you using an SQL DB, and that's why you're using that term?

Comment: I'm using a SQL Server DB, this is where the stored proc comes in.